# Implementing EF6 individual user accounts in a separate entities project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

When creating a new EF6/MVC5 application using the Individual Accounts option you get a web application that has an `IdentityModels.cs` which contains both an `IdentityUser` and an `IdentityDbContext`. I have a separate class library where all my entities reside which has no actual link to Entity Framework because quite frankly in my opinion they shouldn't know about the technology used for storing them.

Other entities reference the `ApplicationUser` so logically I would now like to move my `ApplicationUser` class to the `Entities` library but because it needs to inherit from `IdentityUser` this would mean adding a reference to EF. This messes up my entire idea of putting them in a separate library in the first place.

Does anyone have any experience with the same problem and/or how would you handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, entities never have a reference to EF. They're just classes. Your `DbContext` subclass is what stitches them into Entity Framework. Second, `ApplicationUser` is *your* user. It's not part of Entity Framework; it's merely a class that inherits from the EF model `IdentityUser`. If that's your problem, then you kind of just need to get over it. You can't *entirely* abstract away Entity Framework, unless you just stop using Entity Framework. Otherwise, there will always be a reference *somewhere*.

So, to just combine the two contexts so you can work with `ApplicationUser` within your other entities, you merely just need to change the class your application's context inherits from, from `DbContext` to `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. Then, you can just delete the class that MVC generated for you, after of course switching the reference to your application's context in `AccountsController`. Again, there's no problem here inheriting from `IdentityDbContext` because the context is inherently tied to Entity Framework, anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was already under the impression that I would not be able to get my entities/POCOs entirely independent of EF when implementing an EF authentication method. Your post confirmed it for me.